# How to call same name virtual functions of parents

Tags: c++, multiple-inheritance

```
#include <stdio.h>  

struct Base
{
    virtual void thatSomething() = 0;
    void doSomething() {thatSomething(); }
};

struct DerOne : Base
{
    virtual void thatSomething() override {std::puts("DerOne"); }
};

struct DerTwo : Base
{
    virtual void thatSomething() override {std::puts("DerTwo"); }
};

struct Joined : DerOne, DerTwo
{
    Joined()
    {
        Base::doSomething();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Joined j;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

> DerOne

Why is only `thatSomething` of `DerOne` called? I expect it to be called of both parent classes of `Joined`.

@hvd mentioned that with multiple inheritance I have multiple instances of `Base`.

Also worth mentioning: When I flip the inheritance of `Joined` (`struct Joined : DerTwo, DerOne`), I get

> DerTwo

as output instead.

**Only doing `doSomething()`** in the `Joined` constructor will give me an error for ambiguity of the function call.

When I use **virtual inheritance**, I again get an ambiguity error.

If it is not possible to **call both functions** this way, what other options do I have in order to achieve that with only one line of code that does not address the intermediate classes in the hierarchy or even no line of code implicitly?

Comment: Are you opposed to using `DerOne::doSomething(); DerTwo::doSomething();`?

Comment: I mean it adds many lines of code and that function might be called multiple times where always `thatSomething` of each parent will be called. I could define `doSomething` in `Joined`, but that's just quite wet code. I'd like to automate it

Comment: You can find the reason for this behavior in the reference for [unqualified lookup](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/unqualified_lookup) - and it's not possible to have one function "automagically" call two - a function call has to be unambiguous

Comment: @UnholySheep Is it possible to make a preprocessor script that finds out which classes a particular class derived from in order to call the corresponding functions?

Comment: I got error for ambiguous call [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f96e0eae414e271d) as I expect.

Comment: @Jarod42 Yes, but is it possible to have short syntax without that error?

Comment: C++ does not behave the way you want it to. Either use the C++ way to get the behaviour you want (explicitly call the two base class functions) or use a different language that behaves like you want.

Comment: And can you implicitly inherit the constructor? That would also solve my problem

Comment: C++ is a general purpose language, but the concept of inheritance may not be the best fit. I posted a composition answer.

Comment: I think you might also have a diamond problem in your multiple inheritance.

Comment: @KennyOstrom Yeah, that's what I thought about too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quick fix is simply to have Joined call both, explicitly. 
(edited to override the virtual function)

```
virtual void Joined::thatSomething() override
{
    DerOne::thatSomething();
    DerTwo::thatSomething();
}
```

If that doesn't take care of everthing, then maybe inheritance isn't a good fit.  Composition used to be used a lot more, before all the OOP, and it is still powerful.

If you're expecting a specific thing to happen when you call thatSomething(), but you don't know which one to call, then maybe it's simply not true that Joined is-a DerOne and is-a DerTwo. But it's much easier for Joined to have-a DerOne, and have-a DerTwo, and as many more as you want.

```
#include <list>
#include <memory>
struct DerHandler
{
    std::list<std::unique_ptr<DerBase>> handlers;

    void addHandler(DerBase *p) { 
        handlers.push_back(std::unique_ptr<DerBase>(p)); 
    }

    void doSomething() { 
        for (std::unique_ptr<DerBase> &rp : handlers)
            rp->thatSomething();
    }
};

struct Joined : DerHandler {
    Joined(){
        addHandler(new DerOne);
        addHandler(new DerTwo);
    }
};
```

Comment: Isn't `std::vector` pretty much always a better choice over `std::list`?

Comment: Well, often -- yes, pretty much always -- no. But in this case I'd think vector would be good. No deletes, and the smart pointers are small objects. The important thing is having a container.